# Watching data flow in javascript debugger in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging, runtime, firebug, breakpoints

I have a complex problem to solve. I want to figure out a way where I can create a log of all variables names, function arguments (including function names) and their respective line numbers if any of them match a certain pattern during the execution of a javascript code.

For example, I know I can set a breakpoint on a particular line in JavaScript source and watch the values of the scope variables & function arguments using Chrome's web developer tools. Imagine the following code snippet is a part of a webpage at an URL www.example.com/page.html#stack and I'm watching for the flow of the string 'stack' (the URL fragment) during the code execution:

```
    01. function inform(str) {
    02.  if(str){
    03.    var flag = str;
    04.    alert(flag);
    05.    return 0;
    06.  }
    07. }
    08.
    09. function call() {
    10.  var value = location.hash.split("#")[1];
    11.  msg = value;
    12.  inform(msg);
    13. }
```

I want the output to be the following, because these variables contain the value 'stack' in memory:

1. call->value
2. call->msg
3. inform(msg)
4. inform->str
5. inform->flag
6. alert(flag)

I can do this manually using Chrome's JavaScript debugger by setting breakpoints and watching the Scope Variables section. But is there a way to automate this?

Thanks